# Http post with parameters is working from Postman but not working in my Angular application

Tags: angular, http, post, postman

I have an api call that is being called from an Angular app. The API is tested from Postman and its working. My request in Postman

[image]

I have my Angular code:

```
public getApiResult(input: any): Observable<any>{
    const params = new URLSearchParams();
    let body = new HttpParams();
    debugger
    // params.set('ProductLine',input.ProductLine)
    // params.set('FwProject', input.FwProject);
    // params.set('ValidationType' , input.ValidationType)
    // params.set('UnknownTests', input.UnknownTests)
    // params.set('RequestPayload', input.RequestPayload)
    body = body.set('ProductLine',input['ProductLine'])
    body = body.set('FwProject', input.FwProject);
    body = body.set('ValidationType' , input.ValidationType)
    body = body.set('UnknownTests', input.UnknownTests)
    body = body.set('RequestPayload', JSON.stringify(input['RequestPayload']))
    return this._httpClient.post<any>('http://100.203.304.32:5356/',body)
  }
```

When I try with this I get response as bad request. Data in chrome debug tool:

[image]

The requests look same but I am not sure where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

you are using the HttpPramas as a body.

if you want to send a body you can simply do:

```js
body = {
    'ProductLine': input['ProductLine'],
    'FwProject': input.FwProject,
    ...ecc
    }

return this._httpClient.post<any>('http://100.203.304.32:5356/',body)
```

if you need params you can chain the add method.

```js
let params = new HttpParams()
    .set('id', 'someid');    //you
    .set('name', 'someName');
```

or use a variables beacause httpParam is immutabe and it start a new instance every time you add a params

```js
const params = new HttpParams()
params = params.add('id', 'someId');
params = params.add('name', 'someName');
```

and then you can do:

```js
return this._httpClient.post<any>(`http://100.203.304.32:5356?${params.toString()}`, {}) //if you use post you need to providea empty object as body
```

Comment: `core.js:15724 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 400, statusText: "BAD REQUEST", url: "http://100.203.304.32:5356/?", ` I get this error when I try the second method.

Comment: mmm maybe because is let not const

Comment: check [here](https://armno.medium.com/creating-a-url-with-httpparams-in-angular-42783205f3f4)

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code

```
getApiResult(input: any): Promise<any> {    

    let body: HttpParams = new HttpParams();
    body = body.append('ProductLine',input['ProductLine']);
    body = body.append('FwProject', input.FwProject);
    body = body.append('ValidationType' , input.ValidationType);
    body = body.append('UnknownTests', input.UnknownTests);
    body = body.append('RequestPayload', input.RequestPayload);

    return this.http.post(url, body)
      .map(res => {        
          return res;
      })
      .toPromise();
  }
```